# Angular 2: test http observables combined with a fixture

Tags: http, angular

Component:

```
export class Component implements OnInit {
  private element: any;
  private data: any;

  constructor(@Inject(ElementRef) private elementRef: ElementRef, private service: Service) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.element = select(this.elementRef.nativeElement);
    this.service.getData().subscribe((data: Data) => {
      this.data = data;
    });
  }
}
```

Component test:

```
describe('Component', () => {
  let component;
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [Component, Service],
      imports: [TestModule]
    });

    let fixture = TestBed.createComponent(Component);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  let data = {};
  it('should get data',
     async(inject([MockBackend], (backend) => {
       backend.connections.subscribe((connection) => {
         connection.mockRespond(new Response(new ResponseOptions({status: 200, body: data})));
       });
       component.ngOnInit();
       expect(component.data).toHaveEqualContent(data);
     })));
});
```

The `getData()` observable does not get resolved, and the test will fail with the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'json' of undefined

When I lose the fixture and inject the `Component` into the test, the test will not be able to handle the `ElementRef` and fail with:

> Failed: this.querySelector is not a function

How do you test http observables combined with a fixture?